# How do I change the case (upper and lower case) of strings in my variable?

Tags: bash, shell, variable, string

```
"Enter test: "
read test

if [[ $test == "a" ]]; then
    echo "worked"
else
    echo "failed"
fi
```

It's a simple illustration of test I'm doing, but if I enter "A", it will fail. Is there anything I can do at the variable stage to change it all to small case, so that the test will match?

Comment: Which shell? bash?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several useful ways to achieve this (in `bash`):

**two checks**

```
echo -n "Enter test: "
read test

if [[ $test == "a" || $test == "A" ]]; then
    echo "worked"
else
    echo "failed"
fi
```

**make the input lower case**

```
echo -n "Enter test: "
read test
test="${test,,}"

if [[ $test == "a" ]]; then
    echo "worked"
else
    echo "failed"
fi
```

**regex for both cases**

```
echo -n "Enter test: "
read test

if [[ $test =~ ^[aA]$ ]]; then
    echo "worked"
else
    echo "failed"
fi
```

**make the shell ignore the case**

```
echo -n "Enter test: "
read test

shopt -s nocasematch
if [[ $test == a ]]; then
    echo "worked"
else
    echo "failed"
fi
```

Comment: An extension of (2): `[[ "${test,,}" == "a" ]]`.

Comment: As `=~` is *match* operator you can use [[ Aa =~ "$test" ]]. And so if `[[` (*bash keyword*) is used instead of posix `test` so `[[ "$test" == [Aa] ]]` is acceptable too.

Comment: @Costas `[[ Aa =~ "$test" ]]` doesn't make sense. That matches even `.` as input. Even if the reversal of string and pattern may work sometimes that is certainly not a good idea.

Answer (score 7):

Just use the standard `sh` (POSIX and Bourne) syntax:

```
case $answer in
  a|A) echo OK;;
  *)   echo >&2 KO;;
esac
```

Or:

```
case $answer in
  [aA]) echo OK;;
  *)    echo >&2 KO;;
esac
```

With `bash`, `ksh` or `zsh` (the 3 shells that support that non-standard `[[...]]` syntax), you can declare a *lower case* variable:

```
typeset -l test
printf 'Enter test: '
read test
if [ "$test" = a ]; then...
```

(beware that `bash`'s case conversion is bogus in some locales).

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways to do this. If you're using a recent version of bash it's quite easy: you can convert the case of `test`, or you can use a regex to match both upper & lower case a.

First the regex way:

```bash
read -p "enter test: " test;[[ $test =~ ^[Aa]$ ]] && echo yes || echo no
```

Now the case shifter:

```
read -p "enter test: " test;[[ ${test^^} = A ]] && echo yes || echo no
```

Comment: Note that `bash`'s case conversion doesn't work in all locales. See `a=i LC_ALL=tr_TR.UTF-8 bash -c 'echo "${a^^}"'` which gives `i` instead of the expected `İ` (not `I`) like `a=i LC_ALL=tr_TR.UTF-8 zsh -c 'echo "${(U)a}"'`

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: How annoying! Thanks for that info, Stéphane. Unfortunately, I can't test that example as I don't have that locale (Turkish?) on my system. FWIW, I don't know much about locales, but yesterday I was trying to find an equivalent in Python of `locale -k LC_IDENTIFICATION` ... to no avail. :(

Comment: It's not only Turkish locales. I've just [reported it as a bash bug](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.shells.bash.bugs/22985).

Comment: about your `locale -k`, look at `info libc 'The Elegant and Fast Way'` (especially about the additional symbols in langinfo.h). Those are non-portable, subject to change  GNU extensions.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: I see. `The file langinfo.h defines a lot more symbols but none of them is official. Using them is not portable, and the format of the return values might change. Therefore we recommended you not use them. No wonder Python doesn't give me access to that info.` Oh well. I just wanted an equivalent of LANG="$name" locale -k LC_IDENTIFICATION | grep -E '^(title|language|territory|ident)' which is a handy way to verify that a locale refers to the language that you think it does. IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -ne '/^[aA]$/!i\' -e failed -e 's//worked/p;q' </dev/tty
```